# Converting from float to q7_t in ARM Cortex?

Tags: c, arm, embedded, signal-processing, microcontroller

I understand that the fractional type used in ARM Cortex M4 is used for maximizing the precision of a n-bits number, it is a normalized number from -1 to 1-2^-7 in the case of q7_t.

But how is the typical workflow of its usage?, is it required to normalize and denormalize constantly the variables working with?

I found the next example code that converts from single precision float to q7_t, what is the "128" number doing?

```
float test_float = 3.1416f;
q7_t test_frac = (q7_t)( test_float * 128);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you have a disassembly?

Comment: "_used for maximizing the precision of a n-bits number_" makes little sense. It is simply used to represent +/-1.0 in 8 bits.  Since pi X 128 > 255, the code makes no sense either. The answer to your question regarding 128 is that it causes an arithmetic overflow - not much more can be said.  The data type is intended for use by the associated arm_math.h libraries, not general arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

Q formats are simply scalings from integers to fractional values.

Let’s consider the bits in a byte, numbered from 0 (on the right when the bits are written out) to 7 (on the left). In the common binary notation, bit *i* represents a value of 2<sup>*i*</sup>. The value represented by the eight bits is the sum of the values represented by the set bits, so 01000011 represents 67 (2<sup>6</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>0</sup>).

When two’s complement is used to support negative numbers, the highest bit, bit 7 in this example, represents the negative of its plain binary value, so −2<sup>7</sup>.

In a “Q” format, the values of these bits are shifted. In a Q7 format, bit i represents 2<sup>*i*−7</sup>, except the value for the highest bit is negated, so bit 7 is −2<sup>7−7</sup> = −1. The name may also be written Q0.7. Conceptually, these numbers are tell us where we put a “binary point” (like a decimal point) in the bits to read the value represented. A Q3.4 format has a sign bit, three bits before the binary point, and four bits after the binary point, like 0100.0011, and it represents 4 + 3/16 = 2<sup>6−4</sup> + 2<sup>1−4</sup> + 2<sup>0−4</sup> = 2<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>−3</sup> + 2<sup>−4</sup> = 4 + 1/8 + 1/16 = 4 <sup>3</sup>/<sub>16</sub>.

Another way to think of this is that the bits that represent some *x* in a plain binary (or two’s complement) format represent *x*/2<sup>*n*</sup> in a Q*m*.*n* format.

If your compiler had a fully supported `q7` type, you could just assign values to it without dealing with how they are represented: `q7 x = .25;` would initialize `x` to contain the value 1/4 by putting the bits 00100000 into it.

From your example, it seems you may have a “do it yourself“ Q7 type that is really just an eight-bit signed integer. In that case, you have to do some conversion between the represented values and the Q7 type. Given any eight bits that represent the integer *x*, they would represent *x*/128 in the Q7 format, because in the Q7 format, the bit with value 2<sup>*i*</sup> in the integer format has value 2<sup>*i*−7</sup> in the Q7 format.

Thus, if you have some float `f`, and you want to store it in the Q7 format, using `q7_t x = f * 128;` adjusts `f` to the corresponding value in the normal scaling for integers. Conversely, `x / 128.f` takes the integer value represented by `x` and scales it to what the bits represent in the Q7 format.

Answer (score 1):

Because the [`q7_t`](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/arm__math_8h.html#ae541b6f232c305361e9b416fc9eed263) type only have seven bits to store the fraction, it's suitable to store it in fractions of 128. It simply means that the decimal part of the number is split into 128 equally sized chunks, each which can be represented with the integer values `0` to `127`.

So the integer value `0` represents `0.0`. The integer value `1` represents `0.0078125` (`1 / 128.0`). The integer value `2` represents `0.015625` (`2 / 128.0`). And so on.

Comment: So it is still necesary to normalize the floating point variable in function to an application-specific predefined range before converting to a q type?